# Allow Safely Remove Media in GPO

Tags: group-policy

I have a system that I want to lock down, only running certain programs.

All is working so far when I use "Run only specified Windows applications" (under Local Computer\User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System) except when I try to add an option to remove media.

[image]

I have the policy enabled with a list of all applications I want to be able to load. And this: "rundll32.exe shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL HotPlug.dll"

[image: List of Allowed Applications]

but when I run my shortcut for this I just get the error "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator"

[image: Restrictions Error]

I saw someone online with a similar problem with rundll32.exe but that was with a printer and they got it working by adding a printui.dll. Am I missing something or doing something wrong or is this not possible? I need this option because I have to disable right click in our locked down system.

Comment: I also tried using hotplug.dll, shell32.dll, rundll32.exe, and Control_RunDLL as each their own option under the allowed applications list and that did not work.

Comment: Ended up being a totally different policy that blocked it. Once I changed "Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC settings" to Not configured, the issue went away.